# DotNetCore 2.2 "Receive failed: SSL transport error" with EventHubs Kafka consumer

Tags: .net-core, azure-eventhub

DotNet Core 2.2 application is connected to Azure EventHubs (Kafka)… 
At least once a week (from the output of API-related Linux service) we identify multiple errors reported :

FAIL|rdkafka#consumer-5| [thrd:GroupCoordinator]: GroupCoordinator: Receive failed: SSL transport error: Connection reset by peer (after 43409ms in state UP)

ERROR|rdkafka#consumer-5| [thrd:GroupCoordinator]: GroupCoordinator: Receive failed: SSL transport error: Connection reset by peer (after 43409ms in state UP)

FAIL|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:GroupCoordinator]: GroupCoordinator: Receive failed: SSL transport error: Connection reset by peer (after 43431ms in state UP)

ERROR|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:GroupCoordinator]: GroupCoordinator: Receive failed: SSL transport error: Connection reset by peer (after 43431ms in state UP)

FAIL|rdkafka#consumer-4| [thrd:GroupCoordinator]: GroupCoordinator: Receive failed: SSL transport error: Connection reset by peer (after 43442ms in state UP)

ERROR|rdkafka#consumer-4| [thrd:GroupCoordinator]: GroupCoordinator: Receive failed: SSL transport error: Connection reset by peer (after 43442ms in state UP)

FAIL|rdkafka#consumer-3| [thrd:GroupCoordinator]: GroupCoordinator: Receive failed: SSL transport error: Connection reset by peer (after 43461ms in state UP)

ERROR|rdkafka#consumer-3| [thrd:GroupCoordinator]: GroupCoordinator: Receive failed: SSL transport error: Connection reset by peer (after 43461ms in state UP)

FAIL|rdkafka#consumer-2| [thrd:GroupCoordinator]: GroupCoordinator: Receive failed: SSL transport error: Connection reset by peer (after 43827ms in state UP)

ERROR|rdkafka#consumer-2| [thrd:GroupCoordinator]: GroupCoordinator: Receive failed: SSL transport error: Connection reset by peer (after 43827ms in state UP)

FAIL|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:GroupCoordinator]: GroupCoordinator: Receive failed: SSL transport error: Connection reset by peer (after 1003ms in state UP)

ERROR|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:GroupCoordinator]: GroupCoordinator: Receive failed: SSL transport error: Connection reset by peer (after 1003ms in state UP)

Immediately after that Linux service (API) fails with the following error:

"Unhandled Exception: Confluent.Kafka.ConsumeException: Unknown broker error"

Any help is appreciated.

KR,
Darko

Answer (score 0):

The group coordinator for Kafka clients is distributed across multiple EH nodes and occasionally the connection will be reset and reopened against a different node.  However, this should not cause the client application to fail.  I am interested in checking what condition is causing the unknown server error.

Can you open an issue against our repository?  There is an issue checklist that will help us investigate.  https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-for-kafka